# Could not commit JPA transaction

Tags: spring-data, rollback

I have a problem with my method atomic, i use annotation @transaction of Spring,
In my method test i use a methodeDOA (produitDao.createlist) for create à collection in database Mongodb with spring data, and anthor methode produitDao.testRequired() for provoke a exeption.

==> And all that to test if my rollback is working, but i have thie exeption :

> org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
>       at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526) ~[spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]

this is my principal method :

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class  ,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void createDoaEnsembleProduitEnMongoDB(
        HashMap<Integer, List<?>> mapProduit) {
    produitDao.createlist((List<ProduitDocument>) mapProduit.get(ProduitMongoEnum.PRODUIT_MONGO.getIndex()));

        try{
            produitDao.testRequired();
          } catch(RuntimeException e){
            // handle exception
          }
    }
```

my implement methode doa :

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class  ,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void createlist( List<T> object ) {
    mongoTemplate.insertAll( object );
}
@Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class  ,propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void testRequired() {
  throw new RuntimeException("Rollback this transaction!");
}
```

My goal, if there is an error my create method must do a rollback,

Thank you for your help